# How to Draw the planar embedding of a graph?

Tags: graphs, planar-graphs

I am very interested to know how to draw the planar embedding of a graph.

For this graph:

[image]

I cannot find the planar embedding because it is a Peterson graph, which is not planar;

but for the following graph:

[image]

I am unable to draw the planar embedding.

Isn't the graph itself the planar embedding?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing

Comment: [A graph may have multiple planar embeddings.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/140286/whats-an-example-of-a-planar-graph-with-two-embeddings-whose-geometric-duals-ar)

Answer (score 1):

The graph pictured in your link is almost a planar embedding, except for the three pairs of crossed lines in the outer subgraphs. Move them and you'll have a planar embedding.

Also a word of advice: one intent of this site is to provide an archive of questions and answers for subsequent readers. Links have a way of breaking or vanishing so we discourage their use.

Answer (score 0):

Simply avoid all the crossings.

[image]